# Angular 2 router, Error: Cannot activate an already activated outlet

Tags: angular

I think I can't understand Angular 2 routing at all. I've got this structure in my app:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'login',
        component: LoginViewComponent
    },
    {
        path: 'main',
        component: MainComponent,
        children:
        [
            {
                path: 'unit_list',
                component: ListViewComponent
            },
            {
                path: 'unit_info',
                component: UnitInfoComponent,
                children:
                [
                    {
                        path: 'patient',
                        component: PatientDetailsComponent
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'main',
        pathMatch: 'full'
    }
];
```

Here is how my app.module is looking:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpModule,
        MainModule,
        routing
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        LoginViewComponent
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

And main.module

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        FormsModule,
        RouterModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        ListViewComponent,
        MainComponent,
        PatientDetailsComponent,
        UnitInfoComponent,
    ]
})
```

The problem is I can't manage get router.navigateByUrl function to work.

I have ngOnInit() function inside PatientDetailsComponent which checks if patient is null, if is then I call this "this.router.navigateByUrl("/main/unit_info")", but it throws me the error in the title: "Cannot activate an already activated outlet". It was working fine in Angular 2.1.1, but when I upgraded to 2.4.X none seems to fix my problems. I am also not sure if this routing is correct, because I am a little lost.

This is how my whole routing was looking before upgrading to 2.4.X: http://pastebin.com/Y377STcW

Comment: What is the url of the activated route?

Comment: If I am in PatientDetailsComponent the url looks like this: "/#/main/unit_info/patient"

Comment: this is the same url like a parent.

Comment: I don't know if I understand you correctly. If I am at PatientDetailsComponent level the URL in browser is like I said. So I do this code: if(this.patient == null) this.router.navigateByUrl("/main/unit_info"); and it gives me that error.

Comment: if you understand error message, this outlet is already activated, you need either deactivate it or use another outlet.

Comment: @KamilG : I am facing the same issue . Did u find any solution to this.

Comment: @RomanC : Is there any way to deactivate the outlet?

Comment: @PratikGandhi it appeared to be a missing '}' after some 'if' in my ngOnInit function inside problematic component. I suggest checking your code for errors :)

Answer (score 17):

This error can be a **nasty red herring!**

You may see something like this in the Chrome console:

```
 core.js:1440 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot
 activate an already activated outlet Error: Cannot activate an already
 activated outlet
     at RouterOutlet.activateWith (router.js:6676)
     at ActivateRoutes.activateRoutes (router.js:5765)
     at eval (router.js:5705)
     at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
     at ActivateRoutes.activateChildRoutes (router.js:5704)
```

You'll check your routes and providers and html, and won't find anything wrong.

And then - if you're lucky you'll come across this answer!

And you will scroll up in the console window. And you will see the real error which was pushed off the top of the screen:

```
core.js:1440 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'foo' of null
TypeError: Cannot read property 'foo' of null
```

Then look for the .ts file that corresponds to your component, click on it and it'll take you right to the line of your code with the actual error.

In other words the router cannot survive an error that occurs during construction of your component. The `ngInit` method may have different results - haven't yet tested. In either case the routing is just fine :-)

Comment: Wow is this ever a red herring you are correct! I needed to guard against data in the template that couldn't be bound on initialization as the observable hadn't streamed the data. Once I fixed it, boom activated route went away.

Comment: YOU REALLY SAVED MY LIFE...... i started developing a new application, always running under "serve" mode, but when i wanted to compile it for android almost died trying to debug what was going on, because the menu was showing up normally but wasn't able to SHOW ANY page.!!!!!, you saved me for downgrade the app to IONIC 3.   BEST REGARDS

Comment: The "scroll up for more info" didn't help me. But the "This error can be a nasty red herring!" helped a lot!

I changed in my angular.json "optimization" to false to get more details. Found an error about injecting forRoot router multiple times. That wasn't the case (thank you, grep), but, I did accidentally import AppRouterModule in a child module, which is what caused the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please look at [Child routing component](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#child-routing-component) for a similar example.

I think you should use `RouterModule.forChild(routes)` and add the lines below in one of your `@NgModule`

```
exports: [
  RouterModule
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're not using `ng-component` in your template if you really intended to use `ng-container`.

I'm not sure if this exact error message can be triggered by doing so, but this can result in multiple instances of your component being created and other bizarre behavior.

Answer (score 0):

To add to Simon_Weaver's answer, this is how I diagnosed this aptly named red herring, and got more detail on the error, and a fix:

In angular.json, change build -> options -> optimizations to false.
You might need to increase allowed package size under budgets.
Be mindful that the optimizations option will likely exist in a couple places - choose the right one for how you're compiling (e.g. dev, prod.)

With optimizations disabled, you'll get a lot more details from Angular on what's happening in your code behind the scenes.