# Cannot activate an already activated outlet while refreshing the page

Tags: angular, router-outlet

When I refresh one of my child page I am getting an error saying:

> cannot activate an already activated outlet

Here is my router module ts

```js
const routes: Routes = [{
  path: '',
  component: citComponent, 
  children: [{
    path: 'citorder',
    component: citorderComponent
  }, {
    path: 'citorder/citorderdetails',
    component: citorderdetailsComponent
  }],
}];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class citRoutingModule { }

export const routedComponents = [
  citComponent,
  citorderComponent,
  citorderdetailsComponent,
];
```

i am redireting to `citorderdetailsComponent` from `citorderComponent`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 router, Error: Cannot activate an already activated outlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41893181/angular-2-router-error-cannot-activate-an-already-activated-outlet)

Comment: Am I reading this correctly that you have two routes defined for an empty path?

Comment: sorry  @DeborahK that was an editing mistake ,  i have updated  the code , this is what i have excatly now

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48252110/4431902  this answer solved my issue, any way thanks for your responce